# FTSE Price Feed

Tags: web-services, financial, datafeed

Does anyone know of a web service where I can get price feeds and charts for the FTSE 100 and DOW Jones index?

I only need a delayed price feed not a real-time one.

It is for display on a public website so I assume we'll need a provider that we can pay to license the information?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need real time data, there is [Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance).

For something a bit more professional, you can subscribe to [Reuters DataLink](http://www.reutersdatalink.com/).

There are also [real-time data feeds from Reuters](http://about.reuters.com/productinfo/realtimedata/), but these are for heavy-weight players.

Comment: It's a long time since you've written this answer yet I've been looking for it for so long. Thank you! =)